# Bash Script To Convert Text File of One Line to Multiple Lines

Tags: bash, sh, text-files

I am currently trying to create a bash script that will change a text document of one line into multiple lines.

Example:
`TextFile: Header~someHeaderInfo|Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo|Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo|...|Tail~someInfo`

Again, this above is only a single line.

This should be called through a bash script and be converted into:

```
Header~someHeaderInfo
Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo
Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo
...
Tail~someInfo
```

In the real use case, each Object has upwards of 20 subObjects, each of which may have more subObjects themselves.

How can I go about this separation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if textfile contains:
Header~someHeaderInfo|Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo|Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo|...|Tail~someInfo

The following bash command:

```
sed "s/|/\n/g" textfile
```

Will produce the following output:

```
Header~someHeaderInfo
Object~someObjectInfo
SubObject~someSubObjectInfo
Object~someObjectInfo
SubObject~someSubObjectInfo
...
Tail~someInfo
```

But the OP wants the SubObject on the same line (see comments), so I suggest:

```
sed "s/|\([^S]\)/\n\1/g" textfile
```

That will produce the following output:

```
Header~someHeaderInfo
Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo
Object~someObjectInfo|SubObject~someSubObjectInfo
...
Tail~someInfo
```

Comment: The OP wants a single line for Object and Subobject. I think you're very close.

Comment: Thank you, but Jeff is correct. The '|'s within the subobjects is what's throwing my attempts off.

Comment: sed "s/|\([^S]\)/\n\1/g" textfile will replace every | not followed by a S by a newline... Maybe that's enough to fix your problem (if you don't have any line other than SubObject that starts with a capital S?

Comment: That is enough to fix my problem, luckily the characters for subObjects are distinct so adding those to the array in that command worked perfectly. Thank you!